# Low power latching relay

Tags: batteries, switches, relay, toggle-switch

I have a project to open and close a high voltage circuit (e.g. 240 V) with a relay using low power, let's say 5 V.

Is it possible that I can use it as a switch to on or off the circuit without providing it power (5 V) continuously to close the circuit?
I want to make an electric switch for 240 V which just takes 5 V for an instant to switch only. For example, if I have a 5 V battery I don't want it to drain continuously.
I want to make it like a toggle switch.

Or there are any other options I can use?

Comment: Please structure your question more clearly, describe the problem you're having and make it clear what your requirements are, what your application is and so on. Lists are your friend, and so is detailed background. Solutions always depend on *what* you're doing.

Comment: It is possible yet may cost ~10X as much and require either 2 inputs, Set/Reset or a bipolar Voltage pulse Set+, Reset- since these are less common.   Dont use a battery if you can't afford the power, or use remote powered FET to relay with AC-DC supply. SO relay coil has its own supply from anywhere nearby.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*Figure 1. A bistable relay. Note that A3 is common. Pulse A1 to switch one way and A2 to switch the other. The relay will remain in its last state.*

[image]

*Figure 2. A self-locking 12V single bistable relay module.*

You might consider getting one with a second changeover contact. You can use this to monitor the switching action and switch off the changeover pulse when the changeover is detected.

Always keep your mains wiring well away from and routed separately from the low-voltage control wiring.

Comment: @Neil_UK: Thanks for the grammar fix. I'm well aware of the correct syntax for that one but mis-typed it all the same.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7mR7m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You mean something to latch like the circuit above?

Comment: I need some thing that could turn the 240v circuit on or off electrically

Comment: By electrically I mean through a low voltage signal.

Comment: The problem with the relay is that if I give it power supply it will close the 240v circuit ,,but I have to give it energy continuously to keep the circuit close.as i I don't want to lose that power instead use something (maybe other than relay)

Comment: When you energize the coil, the switch will close and voltage will apply to a step down transformer. With a diode, a DC voltage will continue to energize the coil; without power from the battery being used.
This circuit is only to close the circuit, you need another relay to open it.